# Grand Theft Auto V won't load in Steam on Ubuntu 18.10 using Proton 3.16-9beta ERR_GFX_D3D_NOD3D1X_4

Tags: steam, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, linux, ubuntu

I am not able to get Grand Theft Auto V working on my computer. I have searched the internet and tried everything I could find. So here's the details, hopefully someone can help...

I have installed Grand Theft Auto V on Steam, have also verified integrity of game files for GTA V and Proton 3.16-9beta. When I click Play on GTA V in Steam, Social Club loads, signs me in, then the screen dissapears. A few moments later I recieve the following error:

> ERR_GFX_D3D_NOD3D1X_4 No DirectX 10 or 11 adapter or runtime found. 
>   Please install latest DirectX runtime or install a compatible DirectX
>   10 or 11 video card.
>   [image: ERR_GFX_D3D_NOD3D1X_4 No DirectX 10 or 11 adapter or runtime found. Please install latest DirectX runtime or install a compatible DirectX 10 or 11 video card]
>   [image: Rockstar Games Social Club: No DirectX 10 or 11 adapter or runtime found. Please install latest DirectX runtime or install a compatible DirectX 10 or 11 video card.]

I have renamed the file:

/home/kbd99603/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Proton 3.16 Beta/user_settings.sample.py

to

/home/kbd99603/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Proton 3.16 Beta/user_settings.py

Along with disabling a few of the included options inside it, which I ended up returning them to the original values since it didn't work.

I am using Proton 3.16-9beta, because the game would not start at all after clicking Play with Proton 4.2.

**I am willing to provide more details, logs, etc. Just give me the terminal command to do so, or however. Any help is appreciated! :)**

System Specs

Device: Alienware M17X (laptop)

OS: Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic

OS Type: 64-bit

RAM: 5.8 GiB

Processor: Intel Core i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz x 8
Processor (specs from Screenfetch): "" @ 8x 3.3GHz

Graphics: AMD Pitcairn

GNOME: 3.30.1

Hard Disk: 736.3GB

Kernal: x86_64 Linux 4.18.0-18-generic

Shell: bash 4.4.19

Resolution: 1600x900

Comment: GTA V is not officially supported on Ubuntu according to the Steam Product page for it (it's for Windows only). DirectX is not available on Linux systems.  Are you using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)? You will likely need to.

Comment: Yes, I have Wine on my system. I was just told that Proton on Steam doesn't support GTA V, so I guess I will be resorting back to using Wine. I had GTA V working with wine about a year ago on an older Ubuntu, but of course I have no memory of how I got it to work.